# How can I request a Google pseudonym?

Tags: google-plus

I am looking to request a Google pseudonym. I am just looking for where I can submit this request to.

If anyone is curious, I am looking to have `soandos` be my psudonym for my Gmail account. (~30,000 hits on Google are vast majority me, on SE and other places as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 3):

The link that I was looking for was [here](https://support.google.com/plus/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=name_appeal). Just follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> **Nicknames**
>
> Your nickname should represent you as an individual, and should not be used to represent a business or profession. Don’t use the nickname field for statements or status updates. Your nickname should not be offensive, primarily consists of symbols, or be used to imitate celebrities or historical figures.
>
> To add a nickname to your Google profile...
>
> 1. [Sign in to your Google profile](http://profiles.google.com/me).
> 2. Click **Edit profile**.
> 3. Click on your name.
> 4. Click **More Options**.
> 5. Add your nickname and choose the way you'd like it to be displayed on your profile from the drop down menu.
> 6. Click **Save**, and then click **Done editing**.

[Source](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1228271).

Comment: I do not want a nickname. That will leave my real name shown. Most people I know online do not know what my real name is. I just want to see `Soandos` shown, not First_Name (soandos) Last_Name. I was under the impression from [here](http://gawker.com/5878638/your-google-pseudonym-must-be-approved-in-google-court) and other places that it is possible to request a psydonym. How can I do that?

Comment: @soandos the link in that post lead to a Google+ post by Bradley Horowitz (a Google employee) that links to the man page that is my source.

Comment: What you are saying is true, it is just not what I am asking. I am asking for a way to request that only a pseudonym be shown when I have something posted (be it GDocs, or G+). If you are refering to [this](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113116318008017777871/posts/SM5RjubbMmV) page, I wish to submit a name appeal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Log out of your present Google Account.

Then you create a new account under the name 'soandos'. There's no special process for

Comment: It will not let me proceed with no last name.

Comment: @soandos: Just put something in the box.

Comment: But then extraneous information will be shown in addition to soandos. That is not what I am looking for.